# Python - match string to csv value, then extract adjacent column

Tags: python, string, csv, match, filenames

I'm very green when it comes to Python, so please forgive my disgusting formatting or poor optimization.

I'm trying to write a script to sort files into new folders based on their name.
In order to match their name to the correct new location, I have a csv file with two columns; the first is part of the name of the file, and the second is the correct folder it belongs in.

So far I have everything written to extract the parts of the file names I need, but now I'm stuck as to how I can match the strings I have to a value in the csv, and then extract the adjacent column.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import csv

def openCSV(csvFile):
    file = open(csvFile)
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    data = list(reader)

    return data

def findDemoName(fileName):
    demoName = fileName[16:]
    demoName = demoName[:-11]

    return demoName

def moveFiles(sortingFile, sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory):
    sortingCSV = openCSV(sortingFile)
    srcDir = sourceDirectory
    destDir = destinationDirectory

    for filename in os.listdir(srcDir):
        name = findDemoName(filename)

        print(name)


# begin program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # set the CSV used to sort the files
    fileToSortFrom = '<csv used for sorting>'
    inputDirectory = '<where the files are located>'
    outputDirectory = '<where I want to move the files>'


    moveFiles(fileToSortFrom, inputDirectory, outputDirectory)
```

Right now it just prints the extracted portion of the file name and prints it so I could make sure it was doing what I wanted.

So my next steps are
1. Match the extracted portion of the file name to a matching value in the first column of the csv
2. Take the value adjacent to the match and use it to complete the destination path for the file to be moved to

I found this thread [match names in csv file to filename in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608212/match-names-in-csv-file-to-filename-in-folder), but I don't understand where in the answer the csv is being matched to.

If I need to clear up some points let me know and I will.

Thank you in advance for reading :)

### **EDIT:**

I've tried to stumble my way through this, and here's what I have so far:

```
import os, shutil
import csv

def openCSV(csvFile):
    file = open(csvFile)
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    data = list(reader)

    return data

"""def createReader(csvFile):
    file = open(csvFile)
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    return reader"""

def extractDemoName(fileName):
    originalName = fileName
    demoName = fileName[16:]
    demoName = demoName[:-11]

    return demoName

def moveFiles(sortingFile, sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory, prefix, suffix):
    reader = openCSV(sortingFile)
    #reader = createReader(sortingFile)
    srcDir = sourceDirectory
    destDir = destinationDirectory
    column1 = 'DemographicName'
    column2 = 'DemographicTypeName'
    folder = ''

    for filename in os.listdir(srcDir):
        name = extractDemoName(filename)

        for row in reader:
            if row(column1) == name:
                folder = row(column2)
                destination = destDir + folder
                file = prefix + name + suffix

                shutil.copy(file, destination)

                print('Moved ' + file + ' to ' + destination)
            #else reader.next()



        print(name)


# begin program
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # set the CSV used to sort the files
    fileToSortFrom = '<csv file>'
    inputDirectory = '<source path>'
    outputDirectory = '<destination path>'
    filePrefix = '<beginning text of files>'
    fileSuffix = '<ending text of files>'

    moveFiles(fileToSortFrom, inputDirectory, outputDirectory, filePrefix, fileSuffix)
```

But now I'm receiving the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 63, in <module>
    moveFiles(fileToSortFrom, inputDirectory, outputDirectory, filePrefix, fileSuffix)
  File "script.py", line 38, in moveFiles
    if row(column1) == name:
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem (line 38)

```
if row(column1) == name:
```

it should be

```
if row[column1] == name:
```

> I haven't checked any other logic in the script :)

Comment: Thanks Alex :) this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This script reads the files from the directory you pass in method `move_files`'s `from_dir`.
It checks if the file in the `from_dir` exists in the csv_file and if it does, it gets the location and moves it to that directory.

```
import os
import csv
import shutil


def get_file_sorter_dict(csv_file):
    return dict(list(csv.reader(open(csv_file))))


def move_files(csv_file, from_dir, to_dir):
    file_sorter_dict = get_file_sorter_dict(csv_file)

    for filename in os.listdir(from_dir):
        if file_sorter_dict.get(filename):
            # you can use the location to move the file from csv_file
            # move_to = file_sorter_dict.get(filename)
            # shutil.move(filename, move_to)

            # or you can use to_dir to move the file.
            shutil.move(filename, to_dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    move_files('files_sorter.csv', '.', '../')
```

The csv I am using looks like:

```
name, location
"foo.txt","../"
"baz.txt","../"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks thisshri for responding. I tried this script with the explicit file paths in the csv, like so:
`name, location
"C:/folder/file.pdf", "C:/folder/desintationfolder"
"C:/folder/file2.pdf", "C:/folder/destinationfolder"`
The script runs almost instantaneously but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: The problem is filename in `for filename in os.listdir(from_dir)` is just the name of the file, not the location of the file, that is why `if file_sorter_dict.get(filename)` code is not being run because it is expecting just the name of the file whereas in your situation you have the file location. Try to fix that and it will work.